# WP_Query excluding products

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

I'm trying to exclude results with the name `cable` from the WP_Query.  I have attempted so far but no luck.

Here is my query.  Products that have the word `cable` should be excluded.

```
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'per_page' => '40', 'posts_per_page' => '24','product_cat'=>'garden-lighting','meta_key' => 'total_sales','orderby' => 'meta_value_num','meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'Product Name',
            'value'   => 'cable',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    ));
$args['meta_query'] = $woocommerce->query->get_meta_query();


$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: Just a clarification -- you need to exclude products that have the word "cable" in their title ?

Comment: Yes, i simply want to exclude results with title  LIKE "cable" from the custom post type "product".

Answer (score 1):

The 'meta_query' item you add to the array on the first line is immediately overwritten on the second line with:

```
$args['meta_query'] = $woocommerce->query->get_meta_query();
```

Append your custom query after you've set the WC version.

Example:

```
// Set WC meta query.
$args['meta_query'] = $woocommerce->query->get_meta_query();

// Append custom query array.
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key'     => 'Product Name',
    'value'   => 'cable',
    'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
);
```

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work...the product name is the title of the custom post type `product`.